# Tutorials for creating and deploying a simple java portlet in pluto 2.0

Tags: java, web-applications, eclipse-plugin, portlet

I'm new to portlets and pluto and would like to start with getting a simple hello world portlet up and running on pluto 2.0, but most of the resources I found for this are for earlier versions of pluto or not specific enough for me since I'm new to this area. The eclipse plugin also does not work for pluto 2.0

Please provide links or instructions on how to get started (I already have pluto working...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, try the following Maven archetype:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.myCompany -DartifactId=myApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-portlet
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you give [jetspeed2](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/) a shot. It's build on pluto and seems to be a more
beginner friendly implementation.